# Rest API hook 'rest_insert_post' not returning request object

Tags: rest-api

**Rest API hook 'rest_insert_post' not returning request object**

```
function wp_api_add_tax($post, $request, $update = true){
     wp_mail('abc@gmail.com','test','data'.json_encode($request).  json_encode($post));
}
add_action( 'rest_insert_post', 'wp_api_add_tax',10,3 );
```

It should return entire request object in mail, But returns empty request object altho post object is coming with data

Comment: what is the exact result in the email body ? is it `data[]{post datas here...}` ?

Comment: @mmm Email body data{}{"ID":2733,"post_author":"1","post_date":"2017-10-31 04:26:51","........}

Comment: it looks like a bug of "json_encode" because the variable is not empty, you can see it with `var_export($request, TRUE)` e.g.

Comment: @mmm How we can apply this things in hook ?